# Why do I get this Selenium::WebDriver error in my Cucumber scenario when I visit a page?

Tags: google-chrome, cucumber, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

This method has been implemented in a `**.rb` file in a cucumber project and should compute a `user_id (oid)` and `login`. It suddenly failed by `visit` sending an empty page and this following monster error_message: (by the way no changes in the system are known to me and I can compute the `oid` manually and `login` typing the url directly).

Can anybody help me ?

```
def login_with_oid(oid=null)
    oid = get_context(:oid) unless oid
    visit "/admin/authentifizierung/zidauth?oid=#{oid}"
end


    Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Unknown command 'WaitForAllTabsToStopLoading'. Options: AcceptOrDismissAppModalDialog, ActionOnSSLBlockingPage, ActivateTab, AddBookmark, 
    ...
```

Currently installed:

```
ChromeDriver 26.0.1383.0 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
Google Chrome   29.0.1547.76
```

Under: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Comment: ChromeDriver 26.0.1383.0 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
Google Chrome 29.0.1547.76